# error with spl_autoload_register and not with __autoload

Tags: php, session, spl-autoload-register

I am a bit confused.

I was using __autoload so far in PHP, and i am working with sessions too. Those two things worked fine together, and when i was storing some objects in sessions, the __autoload function has loaded the corresponding classes without problems.

No i was "updating" my main scripts, and wanted to change the __autoload function to the spl_autoload_register function, cause the php manual says, that __autoload could be deprecated in future.

But now, i have some problems. spl_autoload_register works fine with all classes, that i use on a "normal" way in my scripts, but when i store objects in sessions, spl_autoload_register is not able to load those classes.

When i take a look in the sessions with json_encode($_SESSION), theres something like:

```
    {"user":{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"User","id":"1000","username":"foobar","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
```

With __autoload no problems ...

```
    {"user":{"id":"1000","username":"foobar","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
```

my functions:

```
    __autoload($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
```

and i tried to replace it with:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
```

I am using PHP Version 5.3.3-7

Could somebody reproduce this error? is this maybe a bug in PHPs spl_autoload_register so far? 
Is __autoload so far the "better" function to use, and spl_autoload_register not able to work with sessions so far?

Comment: Are you running `spl_autoload_register` at __exactly the same point in the code__ that you were defining `__autoload`? IIRC, objects in the session are unserialized as soon as you call `session_start()`, so if the autoload function is not declared/set before that point, it will not work.

Comment: Its exactly the same point, but you gave me the right hint. I had started the script with `session_start()` and at the next point, i have placed `__autoload()` or `spl_autoload_register`. At this point, `__autoload` worked too without problems. But when i set the `session_start()` behind `__autoload` or `spl_autoload_register`, **both** are working without problems. So `__autoload` works **before and after** starting the session. `spl_autoload_register` only works **before**, and not after starting the session ...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - PHP will detect all function declarations in a file before running any of the code in that file, so `__autoload` exists wherever it is needed in the file. (In the same way, you can run this: `foo(); function foo() { echo 'Yep!'; }` without errors)